# Google Cloud Stackdriver Profiling Nodejs which documentation is right regarding logLevel?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, profiling, google-cloud-profiler

I was adding Profiling in my Google CLoud Nodejs App and i see here in the documentation [docs/profiling-nodejs](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-nodejs#agent_logging) that suported loglevels are

- 0: disables all agent logging (default)
- 1: enables error logging
- 2:
  enables warning logging
- 3: enables debug logging

But here in the Sample App documentation [cloud-profiler-nodejs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-profiler-nodejs#changing-log-level) suported loglevels are

- Setting logLevel to 0 will disable logging
- 1 sets log level to error
- 2 sets it to warn
- 3 sets it to info
- 4 sets it to debug.

So can anyone please tell me which documentation is right and which one is wrong ?

Comment: You can actually check: set it first to 4. If it's not rejected and debug logs start to show up then the 2nd one is right (which is what I suspect). If so you can leave documentation feedback for the 1st one at the top of the page (3 stars or lower I *think* to be able to file an issue) to get it corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question to Google group Forum and got the solution

> The [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-profiler-nodejs#changing-log-level) is based on the Alpha release of Stackdriver Profiler, while the [product’s](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-nodejs) documentation is on the Beta release.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy you noted is now corrected.

https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-profiler-nodejs#changing-log-level
https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-nodejs#agent_logging